# Windows services not Starting

Tags: windows, service, windows-services

I have some xyz **window service**. It is not getting started as a service. But once I reboot the system it is starting fine. What may e the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to goto "Services", and can you see your service there ? Did you try to start it manually ? is it not starting ? if not, whats the error message you are getting ?

Do you have the logic in code to start the service after install ?